# How to access a object field in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, object, eloquent, model

I use laravel framework. I can retrieve data from database with relationship with this code:

```
$orders = Order::with('orderType', 'orderStatus', 'user')->get();
```

The result of the above command is:

```
[
{
  "id":16,
  "shop_id":1,
  "user_id":0,
  "delivery_cost":null,
  "address":null,
  "latitude":null,
  "longitude":null,
  "total_price":655000,
  "total_price_off":551000,
  "order_status_id":5,
  "order_type_id":3,
  "reserve_id":null,
  "created_at":"1399-02-01 13:25:51",
  "order_type":{
    "id":3,
    "name":"admin"
  },
  "order_status":{
    "id":5,
    "name":"system"
  },
  "user":null
}
]
```

My php code is:

```
foreach($orders as $order){
   echo $order->order_status_name; \\ I get error for this line;
}
```

Now my problem is how can i access the name field in order_status? when i want access to total price i write this code

```
$order->total_price
```

and get the total price without any error, but when is write this code

```
$order->order_status->name
```

i get this error:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

Comment: it seems an order has no order_status.

Comment: `$order->order_status->name` is the correct syntax, but if `$order->order_status` is `null`, you can't call `null->name`. Add some code to make sure `$order->order_status` exists; don't assume it does.

Comment: The order belongsTo orderStatus and i get it. we see it in the result. @TsaiKoga

Comment: what about all orders you get, is there one of them without order_status?

Comment: Your code shows a single order, but you're calling `->get()`, which can get multiple orders. If you only want to get orders that have an order status, you need to include `has('orderStatus')`, otherwise, **it's possible that one of your orders does not have an `orderStatus` object**. Also, your output is a `JSON` translation. In php, this would be `$order->orderStatus->name`

Comment: @Tim Lewis I test it, it is null, Why null? if it is null why show order_status?

Comment: As stated at the end of my second comment, use `$order->orderStatus->name`. Your output is a `JSON` representation (notice your `with()` uses `orderStatus`, but the output says `order_status`)

Comment: Try this: $order = $order->order_status, $order->name

Comment: @TImLewis Thank you i fixed my problem with your tips.

Comment: @FarzinBidokhti Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer below to properly close your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your total price always exists as a field, but `order_type` might be empty.

You can use ternary for a quick fall-back in your code like:

```
!empty($order->orderStatus)?$order->orderStatus->name:null;
```

Comment: It's probably `$order->orderStatus`, not `$order->order_status`. Look at the `with()` clause, `with('orderStatus')`. The output in the code is a `JSON` representation, which converts relationships to `snake_case`. Also, `!empty()` is unnecessary; can just be `$order->orderStatus ? $order->orderStatus->name : ''`

Comment: Oh yeah nice catch, thank you for pointing out. My bad missed the relation